# Save Interface in DB golang

Tags: mongodb, go, interface, repository

I want to store my object into MongoDB in golang.
The object 'A' contains a field:

```golang
Messages []*Message `bson:"messages,omitempty" json:"messages"`
```

This array is an array of interface pointers. This is my interface:

```golang
type Message interface {

    GetType() enums.MessageType
    GetId() string
}
```

How can I save this field in mongoDB without creating the messages bson manually?
Today I am creating a bson by iterating on all the messages

This is my insert command:

```golang
_, err := h.db.Collection(collectionName).InsertOne(ctx, A)
```

I tried to convert my array to a `map[string]*Message` and use the bson `inline` flag.

I tried to Marshall the entire object and got an error that there is no encoder to the interface.